# Django 1.6, Haystack: How to print the search's time?

Tags: django

I'm using Django with haystack and I was wondering if it is possible to print the time the search took to show the results. For example:
After each query I want to print: `x results in y seconds`.

Is that actually possible with haystack? Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2):

Haystack by default wraps the search function in a wrapper that times the search and outputs it (see [source code](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/backends/__init__.py#L25)). However, it will only output the information if `DEBUG` is `True`.

What you can do is specify a similar wrapper that outputs the time and dynamically add it to the search backend. Note that you'll need to wrap the method of the specific backend you're using. E.g. if you're using ElasticSearch:

```
from time import time
from haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend import ElasticsearchSearchBackend

def time_wrapper(func):
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    start = time()
    try:
      return func(*args, **kwargs)
    finally:
      stop = time()

      # time = stop - start, now output it wherever you want. 
      print '%.3f' % (stop - start)
  return wrapper

ElasticsearchSearchBackend.search = time_wrapper(ElasticsearchSearchBackend.search)
```

You can time the search on a higher level, including the time it takes to build the query etc., but keep in mind that `SearchQuerySet`s are lazy. You would need to time the first evaluation of the queryset, not the construction.

If you want to show the time it took to the user, consider timing (part of) your actual view function, and pass it to the template context.